# An invalid floating point operation occurred when checking longitude and latitudes

Tags: sql, sql-server, math, latitude-longitude

I know there are a lot of questions like mine asked. I looked at them, but I can't seem to resolve the problem. I'm just bad in math :s.

In c# i'm using a SqlQuery to get cities in a range. This works most of the time, except for some cities.

For example, if i ask the nearby cities of the city with postalcode 2060. I get this error. When i ask it for the city with code 2000, it returns 2000 and 2060.

- 2060: **Lat** = 51.2293515000   **Long** = 4.4279883000
- 2000: **Lat** = 51.2198771000   **Long** = 4.4011356000

this is the query:

```
return base.Database.Database.SqlQuery<City>(
"SELECT * FROM [dbo].[City] WHERE @p0 >= (((acos(sin((@p1*pi()/180)) *
sin(([Latitude]*pi()/180))+cos((@p1*pi()/180)) * cos(([Latitude]*pi()/180)) *
cos(((@p2- [Longitude])*pi()/180))))*180/pi())*60*1.1515*1.609344)"
, radius, latitude, longitude);
```

Can somebody explain how this can be changed so it works for all the "cities" and the reason if this error for a noob in math?

Thank you

Comment: Please format the code.

Comment: Sry, tried to add the paragraph but it just shows the p tags.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that the statement inside acos() gets a rounding error somtimes when you compare cities to themselves, and the statement becomes slightly over 1, which causes the error.

You need to cap the value to max 1 somehow. Here is a rather ugly solution:

```
return base.Database.Database.SqlQuery<City>(
"SELECT * FROM [dbo].[City] WHERE @p0 >= (((acos((select min(v) from (values  (1), (sin((@p1*pi()/180)) *
sin(([Latitude]*pi()/180))+cos((@p1*pi()/180)) * cos(([Latitude]*pi()/180)) *
cos(((@p2- [Longitude])*pi()/180)))) as x(v))))*180/pi())*60*1.1515*1.609344)"
, radius, latitude, longitude);
```

I'm not sure, but it could be that it sometimes gets slightly smaller than -1 as well, which would case the same error. Then you'd have to cap the value to between -1 and 1.

Comment: Thanks. So if the problem occurs when it compares to itself, isn't it possible to add WHERE longitude != param1 AND latitude != param2 and then the acos function?

Comment: Sure, then you'd exclude the city itself from the results. If you want to include them you could use "WHERE (longitude = param1 AND latitude = param2) or ( acos stuff here )", then the acos stuff shouldn't run (i think)